# Only 1 Div Not 100% in Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

So I'm working on a [quick portfolio](http://7shadesofblack.net/portfolio/lk.php) and in mobile, the "email me" does not expand across the entire screen as it should, as seen on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9V4T.png).

I've fiddled around with content width, device width, etc. using numbers, percentages, text values, and nothing has worked to make this page perfect.  I rewrote the code to be cleaner and still can't find my mistake.  Is it just something I'm overlooking?

You can just view my source to get my code, since the CSS should be there.

**UPDATE:** I removed the navigation padding and changed all of the device-width values but now the navigation bar does not go completely across.  I am very confused since the #navigation and #mobilecontact should essentially have the same widths.  I'm using Safari on iPhone.

Comment: Can you add the browser and version that you are testing on, because Email me button looks fine for me in latest chrome - developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the browser and version that you are testing on, because Email me button looks fine for me (occupies entire width) in latest chrome - developer tools.

May be your browser didn't understand **100vw**

If you are concerned about the clickable area of "email me" anchor text.
You can make the anchor as `display:block`, so that it takes up entire row

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using mac safari browser and in safari browser **"vw"** is not supported so now you can use **"px"** or **"%"** and button will be expand.

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to achieve the required result. 
Basically the extra padding you are adding on `<div id="navigation">` (`padding-left: 350px`) is part of the issue.

Also you are incorrectly using the `device-width` attribute value. One cannot specify the width of html elements using `width=device-width;`. Width attribute does not accept device-width as an acceptable value.
So replace that with `width=100%;` or `width=100vw;` **everywhere** you have used it. See here for documentation on responsive web design using [viewport meta tag and device-width](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

I was able to get the button to occupy 100% of the screen width by making these changes.

1. Remove `padding-left: 350px` from `<div id="navigation">`.
2. For `<div id="title">` and `<div id="about">` in the media queries for `max-width: 500px`, changing width from `width: device-width` to `100%` or `100vw`.

Here is the output. Let me know if it works out.

[image]

Comment: I removed the navigation padding and changed all of the device-width values but now the navigation bar does not go completely across.  I am very confused since the #navigation and #mobilecontact should essentially have the same widths.  I'm using Safari on iPhone.

Comment: Hi Lily. So I noticed that the `#mobilecontact` div has `padding:40px` on every side, which actually pushes content out of its expected width of 100%. So you can get the `#navigation` div to the the same width by applying `padding-left:40px;` **and** `padding-right:40px;`. Or just set one of those to 80px, i.e, `padding-right:80px;` **OR** `padding-left:80px;`.
This will make them the same width. Let me know if there is any other issue.

Comment: Please mark as the right answer and upvote if this helped you.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked.. you need to fix following this

1. First of all you should remove "width=500" from your meta, highlighted in below image. [image]
2. Add following in your CSS to fix paddings

   `* {
      box-sizing:border-box;

      }`
3. Instead of `width: device-width` use `width: 100%` and add more properties in #title . see image [image]
4. Update CSS for `#about, #experience, #skills` to `width:100%`
   [image]

and thats it you all are done.

Here is final result

[image]

All you need to do is to fix font-size

Comment: I removed the navigation padding and changed all of the device-width values but now the navigation bar does not go completely across.  Removing width=500 in the meta tag made the page different but not better/worse.  I am very confused since the #navigation and #mobilecontact should essentially have the same widths.  I'm using Safari on iPhone.

Comment: You need to use width: 100%; for all elements that you want to show on entire screen. If it still not works, use display:block; as well

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have a responsive design; you don't need to use specific `Width` for block level elements.

just 
`remove` numerical `width` from `body's children`, then `add`

```
body,html
{ 
    width:100%;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```

and then if you want to set padding or margin to viewport element; the standard way is just one element with specific class handle width like `bootstrap container class`